# Compiling application with Tika with Java 13 - problems loading modules

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-tika, module-info

I'm trying to migrate a Java application that uses Tika from OracleJDK 1.8 to OPenJDK 13.

My IDE is Eclipse.

I have created the file `module-info.java` to indicate the required modules for my application.

In order to be able to use Tika classes such as `AbstractParser`, `Detector`, etc., I have added `requires org.apache.tika.core;` in `module-info.java`.

My code also uses the class `org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParserConfig` to extract embedded images:

```
PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
context.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);'
```

I get the compilation error:

```
PDFParserConfig cannot be resolved to a type
```

Eclipse suggests to add `requires org.apache.tika.parsers;` to `module-info.java`: [Eclipse suggestion screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sQyf.png).

When I add this module requirement to `module-info.java`, the application compiles properly.

That is, at this stage we have included in `module-info.java`:

```
module myapp {
    /** others ... */ 
    requires org.apache.tika.core;
    requires org.apache.tika.parsers;
}
```

However, when trying to execute the compiled application, we get the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tika\tika-parsers\1.24\tika-parsers-1.24.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.tika.parser.onenote.OneNoteParser not in module
```

Inspecting the project Libraries in Eclipse, I can see that tika-core and tika-parsers (v1.24) are both modular: [Eclipse Java Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pb9s.png)

In conclusion: If I don't add `org.apache.tika.parsers` as a required module, the application won't compile, and if I add it I get the runtime error saying `org.apache.tika.parser.onenote.OneNoteParser` is not in the module.

I have inspected the JAR files for these packages to see the dependencies they have. The core packages seems to be right:

```
$ jar --file=tika-core-1.24.jar --describe-module

No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.

org.apache.tika.core@1.24 automatic
requires java.base mandated
contains org.apache.tika
contains org.apache.tika.concurrent
contains org.apache.tika.config
contains org.apache.tika.detect
contains org.apache.tika.embedder
contains org.apache.tika.exception
contains org.apache.tika.extractor
contains org.apache.tika.fork
contains org.apache.tika.io
contains org.apache.tika.language
contains org.apache.tika.language.detect
contains org.apache.tika.language.translate
contains org.apache.tika.metadata
contains org.apache.tika.mime
contains org.apache.tika.parser
contains org.apache.tika.parser.digest
contains org.apache.tika.parser.external
contains org.apache.tika.sax
contains org.apache.tika.sax.xpath
contains org.apache.tika.utils
```

...but the 'parsers' jar gives an error:

```
$ jar --file=tika-parsers-1.24.jar --describe-module

Unable to derive module descriptor for: tika-parsers-1.24.jar
Provider class org.apache.tika.parser.onenote.OneNoteParser not in module
```

Does this mean the jar package for parsers is not well formed?
Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
If I try with version 1.24.1, I get the execution error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\apache\tika\tika-parsers\1.24.1\tika-parsers-1.24.1.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.tika.parser.external.CompositeExternalParser not in module
```

That is: the failing class is `CompositeExternalParser` instead of `OneNoreParser`.

Inspecting `META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.parser.Parser` of tika-parsers-1.42.1.jar`I can see the entry`org.apache.tika.parser.external.CompositeExternalParser` but the package does not contain this class.

So, it seems to be an error in this META-INF file. Id this due to an error when compiling the package and submitting it to Maven Central?

I've found a JIRA issue, [TIKA-2929](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2929), where they say "Apache Tika needs to be on the Java Classpath, not the module path". I've tried this, but, as explained before, I get a compilation error if I don't add it to the module path and set `requires org.apache.tika.parsers;`.

This is a hard puzzle...

Comment: Addressed(but not resolved) in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2929

Comment: The Java Module path doesn't work well for long-lived modules supporting multiple Java versions. Why not just use the classpath instead?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but when I try to set it just in the classpath, the code does not compile. The error is `PDFParserConfig cannot be resolved to a type`.

Comment: You still need import the class into your java code

Comment: In Eclipse (`Properties` / `Java Build Path`), I can see the **Classpath** contains the **Maven dependencies**, and inside this, **tika-parsers-1.41.1.jar** is listed. I understand this means this jar is included int the classpath. However, in order to resolve **PDFParserConfig**, Eclipse requires me to add the module **org.apache.tika.parsers** in **module-info.java**. If I do, it compiles. However, when executing I get the error indicating that a module descriptor cannot be derived from "tika-parsers-1.24.1.jar"

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issues.
Also found the faulty entries in
`org.apache.tika.parser.Parser` (and also `org.apache.tika.parser.Detector`) in `META-INF/services/`

A quick fix is to ...

- Unpack those files
- delete the lines that seem to reference non existing classes
- pack them back into the jar

My project compiled after that.
For sure no longterm solution, but since even older versions i tried ran into that problem, it might help out some people.